# XML or PHP file for storing translation phrases?

Tags: php, xml, performance

I have about 1000 translation phrases. Is it best to store them in an XML file and read in them using PHP on the top of every page, or store them in PHP variables in a PHP file which is included in every page? What is best, especially for performance?

Alternative 1 (XML File):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language name="en">
    <page name="header">
        <phrase name="header_home">Home</phrase>
        <phrase name="header_blogs">Blogs</phrase>
        <phrase name="header_readmore">Read More</phrase>
        ...
    </page>
    ...
</language>
```

Alternative 2 (PHP File):

```
<?php
$header_home = "Home";
$header_blogs = "Blogs";
$header_readmore = "Read More";
...
?>
```

The XML file is loaded using this code:

```
<?php
class Phrases{

    //load phrases to PHP:
    public function load_phrases($lang_id) {
        $xml = new DomDocument('1.0');

        //path to language directory
        $lang_path=("phrases/".$lang_id.'.xml');
        $xml->load($lang_path);

        //phrases are inside page tags, first we must get these
        $page = $xml->getElementsByTagName('page');
        $page_num=$page->length;

        for($i = 0; $i < $page_num; $i++) {
            $page=$xml->getElementsByTagName('page')->item($i);

            //get phrase tags and store them into array
            foreach($page->getElementsByTagName('phrase') as $phrase) {
                $phrase_name = $phrase->getAttribute('name');
                $phrases[$phrase_name] = $phrase->firstChild->nodeValue;
                $phrases[$phrase_name] = str_replace('\n','<br/>',$phrases[$phrase_name]);
            }
        }

        $this->phrases=$phrases;
    }

    //phrases are accessed
    public function lang_id() {
        //determine page language
        $lang = 'en';
        switch(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2)){
            case 'sv':
                $lang = 'sv';
                break;
            case 'fr':
                $lang = 'fr';
                break;
            case 'it':
                $lang = 'it';
                break;
            case 'no':
                $lang = 'no';
                break;
            default:
                $lang = 'en';
        }

        $lang_id = isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : $lang;

        //set the language cookie and update cookie expiration date
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
          $expiration_date=time()+3600*24*7;
          setcookie('lang',$lang_id,$expiration_date,'/');
        }
        if(!isset($lang_id) || $lang_id == NULL) $lang_id = 'en';
        return $lang_id;
    }

    public function change_lang($lang_id) {
         setcookie('lang',$lang_id,$expiration_date,'/');  
    }

    //construct function
    public function __construct() {
      $this->load_phrases($this->lang_id());
    }

}
?>
```

And the PHP file is loaded with a normal PHP include.

Answer (score 2):

For performance, the PHP include file doesn't require any additional external steps, so that will clearly be the winner in performance, compared to opening the external XML file, reading and parsing the data, and assigning variables.

However, you might want to check whether the performance gain matters in your scenario, since modern OSes cache small files entirely in memory, and a thousand items shouldn't add much to the total runtime.

I suggest that if you have access to a MySQL database instance from your web server, you might consider storing these in a database - the performance should fall roughly in between XML and PHP, but using a database in this way is a much better pattern for this purpose.

Comment: I'd definitely challenge that a MySQL database would in fact be slower than reading a single xml file.

Comment: I have seen many people using the XML alternative, but I have never seen the PHP alternative. Why is that? Because you say the PHP alternative will be better for performance, and I think that I will change to this because of this reason. Or is there any other benefits when using XML and not PHP? I mean why are people using the XML alternative and not using a PHP file with variables directly?

Comment: Regarding the MySQL. - I do not want this because that means I need to load 1000 - 1500 rows from the database on every page load, and I do not think that is a good solution.

Comment: @Danie One advantage of using an xml is you can send it to almost any language service provider and they can easily translate it without knowing php. In Fact XML is one of the preferred file types for translation software like [across](https://www.across.net).